# NHibernate QueryOver with SubQuery in where with or

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, queryover

I need to do the following SQL with QueryOver in NHibernate:

```
select *
from Post post
where post.User.Id = 1
or post.Level in (1, 2, 3)
or (select Id
    from SubPost sub
    where sub.Post = post
    and sub.User.Id = 1) != null
```

I don't now how I can do this with QueryOver. The problem for me is how I have to declare the subquery and how can I add it with an `or` condition. I hope, someone can give me a hint. Thank you.

Best Regards, Thomas

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try this

```
Post p = null;
SubPost s = null;
return session.QueryOver<Post>( () => p)
           .where( () => p.User.Id == 1)
           .Where( () => p.Level == 1 || p.Level == 2 || p.Lvel ==3 )
           .JoinAlias( () => s.Post , () => p)
           .Where( () => p.User.Id == 1)
           .List<Post>();
```

i didn't sure really about the second where which is after the JoinAlias, but try it